# Reading models of one app from another app

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Straight to the point.

We're working on a WPF + EntityFramework 6.2 App that's meant to display some data related to another app.

For example: 
 - we have App X and App Y.
 - App Y has to somehow load models from App X and find if a model of certain name is present.

Can this be achieved? Does EF export it's models into a human/computer readable file?

Comment: Move your models to their own assembly/project, now you can reference them from both projects.

Comment: @thehennyy That's what we are doing currently, but we want the program to be more universal and require no modification of App X's solution.